# Turn off cyclmatic complexity in JSHint

Tags: javascript, node.js, jshint, cyclomatic-complexity

I am using JSHint and I want to turn off cyclomatic complexity.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you using jshint? Are you using it with grunt? Which NPM? You need to clarify that if you want an accurate answer.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/)?

Comment: yes with grunt for example i am enabling it just writing in terminal jshint static server where static server are my folders i need to check with jshint

Comment: yes of course i guess it is the first link i found

Comment: This option lets you control cyclomatic complexity throughout your code. Cyclomatic complexity measures the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code. Read more about cyclomatic complexity on Wikipedia. it is all=)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's say our function is named x. Then we should just write  this :

```
function x () {
    /*jshint maxcomplexity:6 */
}
```

Where 6 is number js hint usually says it in console like this:

> static/desktop.blocks/days/days.js: line 57, col 27, This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (6)

Answer (score 4):

I tried at the top of my file to put the following:

```
/*jshint maxcomplexity:0 */
```

And was told

> Expected a small integer or 'false' and instead saw '0'.

So then tried the following

```
/*jshint maxcomplexity:false */
```

And found that it does turn off the cyclomatic complexity warnings.

Answer (score 0):

We can turn off the cyclomatic complexity of functions in jshint via the config file **.jshintrc** like this:

```
"maxcomplexity" : false,       // {int} Max cyclomatic complexity per function
```

Answer (score -3):

Beware. JSHint does not compute cyclomatic complexity correctly. Example:

```
function result(a, b, c) {
  return a || b || c;
}
```

Complexity here is 1; no branches, no loops. JSHint errors if you set maxcomplexity to less than 3. The REPL at http://www.jshint.com also reports 3.